# How to navigate to a view in a region in Prism taking in account namespace

Tags: wpf, xaml, navigation, prism

I've one region, that has several views registered for.

The issue is that they have the same name but not the same namespace. So until now, I was doing this

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionsNames.MainSections, "StartView");
```

But this cannot work, because in my case I've:

- A.B.C.Something.RootView
- A.B.C.SomethingElse.RootView
- A.B.C.SomethingElseElse.RootView

How do you ask to navigate to this?

They have beer registered like this:

```
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionsNames.MainSections, typeof(A.B.C.Something.RootView ));
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionsNames.MainSections, typeof(A.B.C.SomethingElse.RootView));
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionsNames.MainSections, typeof(A.B.C.SomethingElseElse.RootView));
```

I don't want to rename it, we have several modules with the same kind of structure(and therefore name).

Comment: `RegisterViewWithRegion` does not register for navigation, it puts the view into the region immediately

Comment: @Haukinger Sorry for this, you're right, this view is put a in tabbed view, and I'm looking to activate the correct tab.

Comment: that's what navigation is for. Navigating the tabcontrol-region to the desired tab will either create the tab if it wasn't there previously, or show the tab if it exists already.

Comment: @Haukinger but this represent my 4 sections of my applications, they need to be all displayed by default, could this be done with navigation without having to navigate?

Comment: in my applications I normally do `RequestNavigate("main-region", "initial screen")` in `OnInitialized`, I don't see a problem with `RequestNavigate( "main-tabs", "tab1" ); RequestNavigate( "main-tabs", "tab2"); ...` Otherwise, no, navigation without navigating isn't possible ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a unique name for a type when you call `RegisterForNavigation`, typically in the `RegisterTypes` methods of your `IModule`:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<A.B.C.SomethingElse.RootView>("somethingelse_rootview");
```

You can then use this name to navigate to the view:

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionsNames.MainSections, "somethingelse_rootview");
```